# MSBuild cannot find auto-generated files, path with double backslash

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, path, msbuild

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 with some projects in it that I can build properly on my machine, but on the server the build process fails because it cannot find the auto-generated files. I did some testing and found out that on the server, the paths are somehow handled differently and it fails to find the files if the path contains more than one separator next to each other.

The generated path looks like this:

```
"..\..\obj\x64\Release\\\MyProject\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs"
```

On my machine (and others too), the multiple separator (`\`) gets evaluated properly as only one and MSBuild is successful, but not on the server. Moreover, if change the path by hand to replace the multiple slashes it works.

Could there be an option I missed in MSBuild ?

Note: We are working with Windows 7 / VS2012 and the server is a windows server 2008 R2

Comment: What (task, ItemGroup, ...) is it that fails with MSBuild and which version of MSBuild (from which .NET framework)? Have you tried on the command line (using `cmd.exe` and maybe a simple `for` loop). I've attempted to reproduce that both on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 on the command line and using a simple `<ItemGroup>` in MSBuild (2.0, 4.0 x86 and x64) letting it resolve to `%(ItemGroupName.FullPath)`. All works well, no issues with duplicate separator chars.

Comment: We are using MSBuild v3.5 on all machine. In the command prompt we are able to use multiple separators also, ie "cd .\\\\Desktop"

Comment: You could try to resolve the string to a qualified path: <PropertyName>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(PropertyName)'))<PropertyName>, then confirm whether or not the file exists in the location on the server.

Comment: Can you paste the (relevant) part of your project file? That is, the part where MSBuild errors out and (potentially) the part where relevant items and/or properties are defined.